# How to enforce readr to consider correct decimal/grouping mark?

Tags: r, csv, fread, readr

Having csv-files with the European number format style (1234.56 -> 1.234,56) should be handeled by a `readr`  function or `fread()`. Even though `read_csv2()` should be exactly designed for this task, it basically ignores the specification. It only guesses the number formatting automatically. This is problematic if the first numbers with more than 3 digits appear only at the end of the file, i.e. after `guess_max` is reached (1000 by default).

How can I enforce the correct formatting programmatically?

```
library(readr)

data <- data.frame(var1 = c("", 4, 5, "124.392,45"),
                   var2 = c(1, 2, "4.783.194,43", 7))
write_csv2(data, "data.csv")

read_csv2("data.csv", guess_max = 2, 
          locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    NA     1
# 2     4     2
# 3     5    NA
# 4    NA     7

read_csv2("data.csv", guess_max = 3, 
          locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    NA     1
# 2     4     2
# 3     5    4783194.
# 4    NA     7

read_delim("data.csv", delim = ";", guess_max = 3, 
          locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    NA     1
# 2     4     2
# 3     5    4783194.
# 4    NA     7
```

Comment: Being curious: Is it possible to set `guess_max = Inf`?

Comment: it is possible yet receiving the warning massage: `Warning message:
`guess_max` is a very large value, setting to `21474836` to avoid exhausting memory `
Additionally, this somewhat just circumvents the problem. Of course I could look up the number of rows in the data or check, where the first large number occurs, but this is rather cumbersome. Especially when there should be arguments to handle this exact problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `col_types` beforehand seems to help. In this case numeric.

> `col_number() [n], numbers containing the grouping_mark`

```
result <- read_csv2("data.csv", 
          # guess_max = 2, not needed if col_types are specified
          col_types = cols(var1 = col_number(),
                           var2 = col_number()),
          locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))

result
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     var1     var2
    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     NA        1 
2      4        2 
3      5  4783194.
4 124392.       7
```

As Adam pointed out, if you set the col_types, no need for guessing as col_types needs to be the same length as the columns you want to read in.

Comment: In which case, you would remove the `guess_max` argument. Simply `read_csv2("data.csv", col_types = "nn")` should do it.

Comment: ahh, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I missed `col_number()`

Comment: I may be so bold to edit your answer a little bit to be more precise/verbose